# Why relative imports don't work without first importing package as a module

Tags: python

I'm experiment with relative imports and have found very interesting case [here](https://discuss.python.org/t/relative-imports/43183/2):

```
$ mkdir project
$ cat >> project/one.py
from . import two
$ touch project/two.py
$ python project/one.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "project/one.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import two
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

The author explains that

> You must ensure that the pkg package is imported before its contents can do relative imports of each other. There are many ways to do this, but in general you want a program to start with a single absolute import first.

And shows the following solution:

The simplest thing is to run the script as a module, using the package name rather than the source code file name. So this runs without error:

```
$ python -m project.one
```

> Practically speaking, if we want an “entry point” to the code, we should use a driver script that is outside the package, which can find the package by absolute import and use something from it:

```
$ cat >> driver.py
import project.one 
$ python driver.py
```

> That worked because the containing folder for driver.py was on the module search path (sys.path), because of how we started Python - so the project folder could be found directly within the CWD.

Could somebody elaborate on the requirement to first import a package as a module to enable relative imports inside this package? Where is it defined in the spec (link would be good)?

Thanks

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time

Comment: @mkrieger1, thanks, confusing topic indeed :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#the-import-system.

Just like relative paths are resolved against the current working directory, relative imports are resolved against the current package, specified by the value of `__package__`. When you executed `one.py` as a script, `__main__.__package__` was set to `None`, preventing `.` from being resolved as a module. (Remember, `__main__` is the "module" defined by the script.)

When you import `one`, `one.__package__` is set to `'project'`, which is how `from . import two` resolves to `from project import two`.

`python -m project.one` behaves more or less the same as `python -c 'import project.one'` (I'm pretty sure that's not entirely correct, but I think it's correct enough to explain how `__package__` is set.)

Comment: thanks! so basically this is the key point **relative imports are resolved against the current package** [PEP-0366](https://peps.python.org/pep-0366/), if `__package__` is set to `None`, relative imports won't work, right? What happens if it's set an empty string, in the example of `b.py` importing `a.py` where the code is run like `$ python b.py`. If I put `print(__package__)` into `a.py`, it outputs an empty string.

Comment: If a module's `__package__` attribute is `''`, it indicates a top-level module not contained in any package.

Comment: _it indicates a top-level module not contained in any package._ - to clarify, a module with an empty string for `__package__`  still must be imported, right? Otherwise, e.g. run as an entry point script, `__package__` will be set to `None`.

Comment: And according to this comment in the PEP, _setting `__package__` to the empty string explicitly is permitted, and has the effect of disabling all relative imports from that module_. I understand that relative imports won't work neither for an empty string nor for the `None` value, correct?

Comment: Right, both disable relative imports, but for different "reasons" (top-level module vs  script, but neither is in a package). See https://peps.python.org/pep-0366/; prior to that PEP, `__name__` was used to resolve relative imports, so `__package__` was added as an alternative to extracting the package from the current module's name.

Comment: great, thanks for your help, will dive into this more!